# Java back slash character not being output in string

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace some text in a file and the string contains a file path which requires some back slashes, normally using "\" works fine and produces a single \ on the output but my current code is not outputting any backslashes

```
String newConfig = readOld().replaceAll(readOld(),"[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\xxxx\\xxxx\\Config]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"\"` starts an [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html),

> A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.

So, (ludicrously perhaps)

```
String old = readOld();
String newConfig = old.replaceAll(old,
    "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\\\Software\\\\xxxx\\\\xxxx\\\\Config]");
```

Or,

```
String old = readOld();
char backSlash = '\\';
String newConfig = old.replaceAll(old,
    "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER" + backSlash + backSlash + "Software"
    + backSlash + backSlash + "xxxx"
    + backSlash + backSlash + "xxxx"
    + backSlash + backSlash + "Config]");
```

Comment: i tried 3 \\\ and that didn't work, wouldn't have thought 4 would work :p

Answer (score 1):

You should use `replace` here as it may possible your  `readOld()` method may be having some special characters (i.e `+,*,. etc.`) which are reserved in `regExp` so better to use `replace`.(*As `replaceAll` may throw `Exception` for invalid regular Expression*)

```
String newConfig = readOld().replace(readOld(),"replacement");
```

As here it seems you are replacing whole `String` why not just assign `String` directly to `newConfig`

---

From JavaDoc for `replaceAll`

> Backslashes `(\)` and dollar signs `($)` in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a *literal replacement String*

So either go For `\\\\` (As suggested by `Elliott Frinch`) in `String` or use `replace`.